# Storing array of IDs and how to correctly unpack them on a select out

Tags: postgresql

This might be partly a design question (new to PostgreSQL) as well.

I have three tables - Users, Groups and User_Group. User_Group represents a combination of 1 user_id being linked to 0..X Group IDs.

The tables are as simple as you think (for now, building out this thing):

**User**: ID, Name, ....

**Group**: ID, Name, ...

**User_Group**: UserID, GroupID int[], ...

So right now, the GroupID field in User_Group is an Integer array. UserID 1 has a value of {1,2,10,19,28} for example.

**Goal:**
In my UI, I need to represent that list as the group names (ie: {Group1, Group2, Group10, Group19, Group28}).

So, because I am new to PostgreSQL, I'm researching and a couple ideas pop into my mind - unnest, ANY and array replacement. All scream performance issues to me, but I might be wrong (this is the design question, is it smart to store array?)

My query right now:

```
select 
    u.*,
    g.group_ids
from users u
left join user_group g
    on u.id = g.user_id
```

Piece I'm trying to figure out how to push into:

```
select ug.group_id 
from (select unnest(group_ids) group_id FROM user_group) as ug
left join groups g 
    on g.id = ug.group_id
```

This will just result in (obviously) an additional row for each group ID the person is associated with.

Which is the best way to do this?

Comment: Instead of 3 tables, why don't just use two tables (User and Group)? For one-to-many relation, you don't need a link table. just User (id, name) and Group (user_id, whatever).

Comment: Could do that - I mainly separated the two because groupIDs will be updated more frequently than other fields and it helps with reporting purposes with other queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

( Personally I would have a column on Users table as Groups (int array) but your choice is fine too).

It would look like (I used table and field names off the top of my head, slightly modified than yours):

```
select u.*, g.Name as GroupName
from users u
left join usergroups ug on ug.UserId = u.UserId
left join groups g on g.groupId = ANY( ug.groups );
```

Update: I might have misunderstood your need. Maybe you meant this:

```
select u.*, 
  (select string_agg(g.name,',') 
   from groups g 
   inner join usergroups ug on ug.groupId = g.GroupId
   where ug.UserId = u.UserID and 
         g.groupId = ANY( ug.groups )) as Groups
from users u;
```

Comment: This didn't exactly help, but this gave me the tip of using string_agg - which gave me my solution! I will update and accept this.

Answer (score 0):

There, you have a one-to-many relationship:

User (1)->(*) Groups

This kind of relation doesn't need an intermediary table for the link definition. The one-to-many relation use to have a foreign key in the child table (in this case is Groups).

The result will be:

- User: id, name
- Group: id, name, user_id
- And you can add a constraint to the database as: `ALTER TABLE user ADD CONSTRAINT fk_user FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES group;`

Comment: For now, this isn't an option - But I totally understand why I should do it. Long story. But thank you!